# ACP (PCA) with R with Excel xxls imported File and numerical variables

Tags: r, excel, pca, numeric

I'm trying to make a statistic acp (French) OR pca (English) method on a xls imported file in R.

After the code below, I get this error message, I've tried several others solutions of code.

My data in columns must be numerical, and they are in in the files written like this : 12.5, 24, 32.4.... in each cell. I modified Type of data (in numerical) while importing, and no change.

Is the fact of point in cell for decimal representation that cause problem?

```
library(FactoMineR).
library(readxl)
ACP_DATA_TABLEUR <- read_excel("C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/ACP DATA TABLEUR.xlsx")
View(ACP_DATA_TABLEUR)
res.pca <- PCA(ACP_DATA_TABLEUR, graph = FALSE)
```

Error in PCA(ACP_DATA_TABLEUR, graph = FALSE) :

```
The following variables are not quantitative:  X
The following variables are not quantitative:  H1
The following variables are not quantitative:  H2
The following variables are not quantitative:  H3
The following variables are not quantitative:  H4
The following variables are not quantitative:  H5
The following variables are not quantitative:  H6
The following variables are not quantitative:  H7
The following variables are not quantitative:  H8
The following variables are not quantitative:  H9
Precision : H1 cannot be quantitative but a chain of caracters in my modelisation
```

What can be the solution to change this error?

Comment: It would help if we could see a sample of your data.  Please type `dput(head(ACP_DATA_TABLEUR))` and paste the results into your question so that we can help.

Comment: I've got the same problem with the `PCA` function

Comment: Maybe you should contact the authors of the `FactomineR` package

Comment: Perhaps R did not understand during import that your variables are quantitative and misinterpreted the numbers as characters or made "factors" out of it. But without a sample of your data it is impossible to definitely say (as @G5W correctly pointed out)

Comment: My code used to run, but now I get the same error message : `The following variables are not quantitative: `